# Insert record if not present for all keys in master table

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, dml

I have two tables as mentioned below

Table1 contains the key

```
| key  |  
| k1   |
| k2   | 
| k3   |
```

Table2 contains the mapping of key with resource

```
  | res  |   key    |
  | r1   | k1       |
  | r1   | k2       |
  | r2   | k1       |
```

Final goal is to have a mappings in table2 for each resource with each key.
As table2 is not complete, so i need to insert mappings which are not present.

So How to find out which resource - key mapping is missing in tale2
and then insert them into table2

as below keys are missing in table2

```
| res| key  |  
| r1 | k3   |
| r2 | k2   | 
| r2 | k3   |
```

So finally table2 would look like below.

```
  | res  |   key    |
  | r1   | k1       |
  | r1   | k2       |
  | r1   | k3       |
  | r2   | k1       |
  | r2   | k2       |
  | r2   | k3       |
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think you should also provide the resource table.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos there is no resources table. Goal is to have All the distinct resources values in table2 should have exactly one mapping present in table2 itself.

Comment: @Rishi Why are you renumbering the ids in your final output? Presumably they're just a surrogate primary key that's populated via a sequence?

Comment: @Boneist no they are not primary key. i just used them here to show the sequence. In my real table  I have composite key which uses res column

Answer (score 1):

I would question the need for every combination to exist in the table, since that means that the table either isn't storing relevant data (i.e., if every combination exists then you can just assume that and don't need to put it into a table) or there are some columns that you haven't shown and you're going to be putting rows into your table with those columns NULL as "placeholders", which is adding a bunch of "non-data" to the database.

Anyway, this should do what you need:

```
INSERT INTO Table_2 (resource, key)
SELECT
    R.resource,
    T1.key
FROM
    Resources R
CROSS JOIN Table_1 T1
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM Table_2 T2
        WHERE
            T2.resource = R.resource AND
            T2.key = T1.key
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. These are language translations DB tables. You can consider it as r1 as resource and k1 , k2 , k3 are its translation in three different languages. So presently the translations are missing for different languages and we need to insert default values.

Answer (score 0):

[Partition outer join](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=312) plus a filter for null rows to the rescue!

```
with t1 as (select 1 id, 'k1' key from dual union all
            select 2 id, 'k2' key from dual union all
            select 3 id, 'k3' key from dual),
     t2 as (select 1 id, 'r1' res, 'k1' key from dual union all
            select 2 id, 'r1' res, 'k2' key from dual union all
            select 3 id, 'r2' res, 'k1' key from dual)
-- end of mimicking tables t1 and t2 with your data in them. You would not need these subqueries.
-- Run the sql below, substituting in your table names as appropriate.
select t2.res,
       t1.key
from   t1
       left outer join t2 partition by (t2.res) on (t1.key = t2.key)
where  t2.id is null;

RES KEY
--- ---
r1  k3 
r2  k2 
r2  k3
```

As for your additional requirement to add in the missing rows, it's as simple as:

```
insert into t2 (id, res, key)
select t2_seq.nextval,
       t2.res,
       t1.key
from   t1
       left outer join t2 partition by (t2.res) on (t1.key = t2.key)
where  t2.id is null;
```

This assumes you've got a sequence populating the id column for your table t2.